# Creating Calendar With Task Scheduling Using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, calendar

I want to create a calendar with the following features in picture[image]

I want to have the time in the left column and the task in the bottom area. I want to drag a task from the bottom list and schedule it in the specified time on specified day.

How can I do this?

Comment: Nobody will tell you how to do it unless you provide some code with the specific question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/external-dragging.html .